# I have a prop with building my flutter app

Tags: android, flutter, gradle

When I run my app an error message below is shown:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on AOSP on IA Emulator in debug mode…
lib\main.dart

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Could not open settings remapped class cache for bq3hllkgb26p0nrblf5gh8d37 (C:\Users\amabd.gradle\caches\5.6.2\scripts-remapped\settings_dok3hc1t57922ptib73pz9y10\bq3hllkgb26p0nrblf5gh8d37\settings8410a2d21ed2f87c8a0398566330ee52).
Could not open settings generic class cache for settings file ‘D:\projects\flutter\photo\photos\android\settings.gradle’ (C:\Users\amabd.gradle\caches\5.6.2\scripts\bq3hllkgb26p0nrblf5gh8d37\settings\settings8410a2d21ed2f87c8a0398566330ee52).
BUG! exception in phase ‘semantic analysis’ in source unit ‘BuildScript’ Unsupported class file major version 57

Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
BUILD FAILED in 3s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)
```

Could anyone help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Try 'flutter clean' before run

Comment: I tried it and the error is still appearing.

Comment: I have the same problem when trying to deploy fullter app on my device

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer..
you should delete flutter SDK and reinstall it .then make the last update to it by:

```
flutter upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to this folder and delete all cached files.

```
  C:\Users\amabd.gradle\caches
```

Then try to restart the project.

Comment: I deleted all chaced files and the error is still appearing

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem after hours of searching and removing android studio. I downgraded java to java-8 and set java_home in OS and it worked like a charm.